# Regex error when trying to addParser with tablesorter

Tags: jquery, regex, tablesorter

I am trying to use tablesorter jquery library to sort a column of time/dates. I am having trouble with the regex and sorting it. Can someone help? My time/date format is:

2:06 PM

Thu Mar 28

Like this. With the date on a separate line. 
My regex is this:

```
/$(\d{1,2}):(\d\d):(\d\d) (a\.m\.|p\.m\.) (\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/
```

and my function to parse the date is:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'DateParser',
        is: function(s) {
                return false;
        },
        format: function(s) {
                var date = s.match(/$(\d{1,2}):(\d\d):(\d\d) (a\.m\.|p\.m\.) (\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/)
                var d = date[1];
                var m = date[2];
                var y = date[3];
                var H = date[4];
                var M = date[5];
                var S = date[6];
                var MS = 0;

                return new Date(y, m, d, H, M, S, MS).getTime();
        },
        type: 'numeric'
});
```

The error I am getting is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null "
when seen with google chrome. I think the best way to do this is by using regex. But if I am mistaken then I am willing to change for a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: It may be best to use a date library like `momentjs` or `datejs`.

Comment: Where does year come from when it's not present in `s`? What separates the two lines? Why d,m,y,H,M,S is that order when `s` is in a different order? Too many questions.

Comment: The shared regex is made to parse something like this: `99:99:99 a.m. 99/99/9999`, but only if you remove the first `$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
s.match(/^(\d{1,2}):(\d\d) (AM|PM)\n(\w+) (\w+) (\d{1,2})$/)
```

`$` matched the *end* of a string. You want `^` to match the beginning. `\n` matches the newline. `\w` matches letters.

Then, the order of output, from 1 to 6, is:

```
["2", "06", "PM", "Thu", "Mar", "28"]
```

Comment: You will need to use your noggin.